# Set result caching to off in redshift jdbc driver

Tags: jdbc, amazon-redshift

I am doing a performance test on redshift. Is there a way to turn off the result caching through JDBC driver. I have tried passing ("enable_result_cache_for_session", "off") as connection properties but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `session` referred to in this variable is all queries issued by a single connection. The setting does not apply to other connections and does not persist.

You have to issue `SET enable_result_cache_for_session TO off;` in every connection. Many benchmarking tools or scripts create a new connection for every query they run.

UPDATE: I forgot that you **can** assign the setting to a user in a persistent way using `ALTER USER`

```sql
ALTER USER master SET enable_result_cache_for_session TO off;
-- ALTER USER

\q -- << disconnect then reconnect >> 

SHOW enable_result_cache_for_session ;
--  enable_result_cache_for_session
-- ---------------------------------
--  off
```

Comment: Since issuing this query would add time in overall perf results. Is there any DB level flag to switch it off

Comment: It takes milliseconds and will not add meaningful time in a Redshift performance test.

Comment: There is a persistent way to change this that I forgot about, I updated the answer.